# What are the system requirements for GraalVM?

Tags: java, quarkus, graalvm

I did research on this, but I couldn't find an answer...

I want to use GraalVM for quarkus development
What are the system requirements of it (Will it run on a surface 3)?

Thanks for your answers...

Comment: There are not hard requirements, if you can install java, usually you can install graalvm

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just using GraalVM as a JDK, then same as any other JDK.
But If you are using GraalVM native-image then there are requirements depends on the OS you are using it on:

1. Linux: install glibc-devel,  zlib-devel, gcc, and libstdc++-static
2. MAC OS: install xcode
3. Windows: Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC) that comes with Visual Studio 2017 15.5.5 or later and you need to run it on x64 Native Tools Command Prompt.

Check this link for more details: https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/

there are other components also in GraalVM, which you can download using gu utility